# GCM BroadcastReceiver receives older notifications

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I implemented a GCM Client in my Android App but for some reason, whenever I get a new notification, the broadcast receiver receives a bunch of older notifications I already read.

Here's my GCM BroadcastReceiver

```
public class GCMBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "GCMBroadcastReceiver";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "RECEIVED ");
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GCMIntentService.class.getName());

        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));

        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

And here is my GCMIntentService

```
public class GCMIntentService extends IntentService {
private static int NOTIF_ALERTA_ID = 1;
private static String MSG = "message";
SharedPreferences gcmPrefs;
static NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

    public GCMIntentService() {
        super("GCMIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {

                gcmPrefs = getSharedPreferences(RegistrationManager.GCM_PREFS,
                        MODE_PRIVATE);
                boolean shouldNotify = gcmPrefs.getBoolean(
                        RegistrationManager.PROPERTY_SHOULD_NOTIFY, false);

                if (shouldNotify) {
                    showNotification(extras.getString(MSG));
                }
            }
        }

        GCMBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

    private void showNotification(String msg) {
        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(msg).setLargeIcon(icon);
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

        // Here i Should launch the proper activity
        Intent notIntent = new Intent(this, TimelineActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                notIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contIntent);

//      // Vibration
//      mBuilder.setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 });
//
//      // LED
//      mBuilder.setLights(Color.BLUE, 3000, 3000);
//      
//      Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
//      mBuilder.setSound(alarmSound);

        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIF_ALERTA_ID, mBuilder.build());

        NOTIF_ALERTA_ID++;
    }

    public static NotificationManager getmNotificationManager() {
        return mNotificationManager;
    }

}
```

Any ideas why am I receiving old notifications? Thanks in advance

Comment: Carla, if you getting already read notification, that means server are sending you lots of notification at a time, I think its the server issue from where you getting notification.

Comment: Thank you, it was indeed something wrong at the server!

Comment: Its okay, carry on...happy coding!!!